# Add class to transcluded element

Tags: angularjs

Let's say I have a directive that looks like this:

```
<input class="icon-input" type="text">
```

I want to end up with this:

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
  <i ng-class="icon"></i>
  <input class="icon-input" type="text" class="form-control">
</div>
```

(Th significant part above is `class="form-control"`.)

My directive currently looks like this:

```
'use strict';

class IconInput {
  constructor() {
    this.restrict = 'C';
    this.replace = true;
    this.transclude = 'element';
    this.templateUrl = 'app/form-fields/icon-input/icon-input.html';
    this.scope = { icon: '@' }
  }
}

export default IconInput;
```

How can I add `class="form-control"` to my transcluded `input` element?

Comment: You should transclude the input only, and pass the classe from outside, int the input definition.

Comment: What do you mean by "transclude the input only"? I thought that was what I was doing.

Comment: The way you are doing, everything get replaced for the template. If you use ng-transclude as part of the template It will replace for the original input + the rest of the template.

Comment: You can see something similar here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22931740/angularjs-directive-wrap-content-and-keep-attributes-on-original-element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up figuring it out myself.

```
'use strict';

class IconInput {
  constructor() {
    this.restrict = 'C';
    this.transclude = true;
    this.scope = { icon: '@' };

    this.compile = (element, attrs, transclude) => {
      return $scope => {
        transclude($scope, clone => {
          element.append(clone)
            .wrap('<div class="col-xs-12"></div>')
            .before(`<i class="fa ${$scope.icon}"></i>`)
            .addClass('form-control');
        });
      };
    };
  }
}

export default IconInput;
```